# Roses counting problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

You have an unlimited supply of red roses, pink roses, yellow roses and white roses.

a - How many ways can you order a bouquet of a dozen roses?

b - How many ways can you order a bouquet of a dozen roses if you want to have at least one of each kind?

c - How many ways can you order a bouquet of a dozen roses if the store only has six pink roses?

So I know that we can count it by permuting a dozen, $12!$, but b and c are throwing me off since the number is not given. My attempt is to divide the dozen into equal groups of $4$ and count it as $12\cdot11\cdot10\cdot9$. Can you give me a conceptual explanation and not just the answer?

The only thing that matters for (a) is how many roses are in the basket.

Comment: Are you sure order of roses within a bouquet matters? For eg if the flowers are in a circle or if only the mix is important, the counts could be different.

Comment: I think "order" here means "ask the flower shop for", not "put in order".  So eight red and four pink is the same as four pink and eight red.  Please confirm.

Comment: That sounds logical.

Answer (score 0):

If you think (like I do) a bouquet is unordered, so four reds and eight pinks are the same as eight pinks and four reds, this is a [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) problem.  Let me start with (b).  There are $12$ roses-put them in a row, so $11$ spaces between them.  You can choose three of those spaces to put a divider, which indicates where the transitions are from red to pink to yellow to white.  This you can do in ${11 \choose 3}=165$ ways.  The fact that two dividers can't occupy the same place guarantees that you have at least one of each color.  Now to (a)-do the same with sixteen roses, where the number you deliver is one less than the number from the exercise.  Now you can have no roses of a color delivered if the original selection has only one. By the same logic, there are ${15 \choose 3}=455$ ways.  For (c), think of the pinks being the first color in the problem.  I will assume the restriction of having at least one of each color has been lifted.  Then you do the same as (a) with $0$ to $6$ pinks, which is ${14 \choose 2} + {13 \choose 2}+ \ldots {8 \choose 2}$.  The choose $2$ is because there are only three colors now and the $15=12+3$ becomes $14=12+2$ because there are only two breaks to choose.

Comment: For c, im a little confused why you chose 16 spots, as for 15 choose 2. Can you explain that part please?

Comment: @user67527:  I thought having no roses of some color(s) was acceptable, so the $16$ is the same logic as in part a.  But the pinks are already accounted for, so it should be one less.  I'll fix.